# Object rendered appears then disappears

Tags: rendering

I have an object which I'm trying to render, when I render it appears during the process of rendering but then disappears, not sure why?

[image]

Comment: check down at the bottom rigth corner, maybe you have selected a different composition layer? Could you also provide the blend file so we can check on it? you cut out quite a lof in the gif

Comment: There is a chance the first time (when it appears) you're seeing your render layer. The second time it's the result of compositing. Go to compositor and make sure you have your render layer plugged in your compositor output.

Comment: @DrachenSeele here is the blend file https://www.dropbox.com/s/udnkgk6efbnleiy/Skel.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok I found the mistake.
you had the view layer set to coposite, and this means it goes throu the compositor first and then goes to the output,[image]

and when I then look at your compositer you can see that you you selected IndexOB in the Alpha channel, using the viewernode I was able to see that the IndexOB output ist empty (Black) and thus everything was transpatent [image]

This was an easy fix, I selected the object and added an Pass Index in the Object menu, then in the compositor I added the ID Mask node between IndexOB and the output to select this specific Index[image]

and now the render is as you wanted it to be[image]

Comment: Thanks and where is the rendered image saved?

Comment: this is up to you to decide, when you press F3 in 2.7 or Shift+S in 2.8 you can select where to save it. or when doing an animation you have to look in the output section of the propperties pannel to set it there